# How to write this trigger for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Suppose that I have a table `my_table(id, x, y)`. I want to write a trigger to prevent updating the `y` col and setting it to a `non-null` value if `x` is already `null`. As SQL Server doesn't have a before update trigger, how can this be done? Apparently we can use an `instead of` trigger for this purpose, but how can we check the old and current values and decide whether we should raise an error or let the update execute normally?

Example:

Let's pretend we have this row in the DB:

```
1, null, null
```

Then this should fail (raise error)

```
update my_table set y = 'blah' where id = 1;
```

But this should succeed:

```
update my_table set y = null where id = 1;
```

I know the example isn't very meaningful, but it is similar to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ninja - just to be clear, if `x` is `null`, what do you want to happen to `y`?  Set it to an arbitrary non-null value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but I am not sure what other edge conditions you need to handle:

```
create table my_table (id int identity, x varchar(20), y varchar(20))
go 
CREATE TRIGGER tgNotNullYonMyTable
ON my_table
FOR UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE(y)
   BEGIN
       IF exists (
                  select 1 
                    from deleted d 
                         join inserted i on i.id = d.id 
                   where (d.x is null or i.x is null)
                         and i.y is null
                 ) 
          BEGIN
              RAISERROR ('Leave Y alone if x is null.', 16, 1)
              rollback tran
          END
   END
go

insert my_table values (null,null)

go 

update my_table set y = 'blah' where id = 1;
go 
update my_table set y = null where id = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER yxnull
ON mytable
FOR UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE(y)
   BEGIN
       IF deleted.x is null and inserted.y is not null
          BEGIN
              RAISERROR ('Leave Y alone if x is null.', 16, 1)
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

          END
   END
go
```

Comment: This isn't working. SQL Server complains that the multi-part identifier deleted.x cannot be found.

Comment: I downvoted this cause it does not even parse, deleted is a "virtual table" see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx